# How do I grant the mlock syscall to a container invoked via "sudo rkt run" on CoreOs

Tags: coreos, linux-capabilities, rkt

Running my app as below:

`sudo rkt run --insecure-options=image --interactive --net=host ./myapp.aci`

I get the message:

> Failed to lock memory: cannot allocate memory

Which after some digging would seem to indicate that the container does not have the `CAP_IPC_LOCK` capability passed to it. I have dug into some of the documentation, but cannot find where I need to add configuration or any option to enable this. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ACIs can specify which caps they need in their manifest with an [isolator of type os/linux/capabilities-retain-set](https://github.com/appc/spec/blob/master/spec/ace.md#oslinuxcapabilities-retain-set).

To check if the manifest contains such an isolator, you can use actool:

```
$ actool cat-manifest --pretty-print ./myapp.aci
```

You might see the following:

```
    "isolators": [
        {
            "name": "os/linux/capabilities-retain-set",
            "value": {
                "set": [
                    "CAP_IPC_LOCK"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
```

To add `CAP_IPC_LOCK`, you can use:

```
$ actool patch-manifest --capability=CAP_IPC_LOCK --replace ./myapp.aci
```

It is currently not possible to add a capability directly on the `rkt run` command line. I filed an issue on GitHub for this feature request: [coreos/rkt#2371](https://github.com/coreos/rkt/issues/2371)

Comment: Thanks, I had come to a conclusion close to this, but thought I'd give someone else a chance to answer it. I was unaware of the patch-manifest function before, I had set up my ACI build process to modify it with jq, thanks! I also found for it to work I also had to untar the ACI, use "setcap cap_ipc_lock=+ep" on the executable and then recreate the ACI using bsdtar in order for the capabilities of the executable to be preserved as acbuild copy did not keep these attributes in the initial ACI. Add this to your answer for completeness, or provide an alternative, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use acbuild to give your container the right capabilities.

If you're already using acbuild to make your ACI, just add this line to the build script:

`echo '{ "set": ["CAP_IPC_LOCK"] }' | acbuild isolator add "os/linux/capabilities-retain-set" -`

Or if you're not already using acbuild to make your ACI, you can modify an existing ACI by using the `--modify` flag. So the command would be:

`echo '{ "set": ["CAP_IPC_LOCK"] }' | acbuild --modify path/to/your/app.aci isolator add "os/linux/capabilities-retain-set" -`

Comment: Useful to know that I can do this using acbuild, too. Any more info on whether "setcap cap_ipc_lock=+ep" status on the executable in the archive can be retained in any other way than by depackaging/setting capability/repackaging via bsdtar as per my comment to the other answer?

Comment: If there's a `setcap` binary in the ACI you can run it with `acbuild run`, but if not then I think the only way to do it is the bsdtar way.

Comment: Thanks, will see if there's an issue against acbuild for preserving cap flags on 'copy', and if not, open one. I'm going to award the answer to @Alban as that answer got there first on the isolator setting.